# Using Testng in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, testng, eclipse-juno

I am using Eclipse Juno. I installed TestNG plugins properly. But when I want to run test I can't find a TestNG option in Run As. What's the matter?

My Class is

```java
package com.oasisdigital.rental.client;

import static javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.CREATED;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.contains;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.empty;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.notNullValue;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.oasisdigital.rental.test.AbstractIT;

@Test
public class ClientResourceIT extends AbstractIT {

    private ClientApi clientApi;

    @Override
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();

        this.clientApi = new ClientApi(api);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnEmptyListWhenNoProviders() {
        assertThat(clientApi.getClients(), is(empty()));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnClientAfterCreation() {
        Response resp = clientApi.postClient("Jimmy");
        assertThat(resp.getStatus(), is(CREATED.getStatusCode()));

        ClientDto client = resp.readEntity(ClientDto.class);
        assertThat(client.getId(), is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(client.getName(), is("Jimmy"));

        assertThat(clientApi.getClients(), contains(client));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a simple class, annotate one method with @Test and try. If you still don't get it, can you check if you get testng options at other places eg. Window -> Preferences, Views etc

Comment: hello sir,can you explain more,please.